# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'iterator') in Kotlin Multiplatform

Tags: javascript, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-js

I am trying to run a kmm project js files on a browser. Here the html:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <script src="../packages_imported/kotlin/1.5.10/kotlin.js"></script>
  <script src="../packages_imported/KotlinBigInteger-bignum-js-legacy/0.3.2/KotlinBigInteger-bignum-js-legacy.js"></script>
  <script src="../packages_imported/kotlinx-coroutines-core/1.5.0-native-mt/kotlinx-coroutines-core.js"></script>
  <script src="../packages_imported/ktor-ktor-io-js-legacy/1.6.0/ktor-ktor-io-js-legacy.js"></script>
  <script src="../packages_imported/kotlinx-serialization-kotlinx-serialization-core-js-legacy/1.2.1/kotlinx-serialization-kotlinx-serialization-core-js-legacy.js"></script>
  <script src="../packages_imported/kotlinx-serialization-kotlinx-serialization-json-js-legacy/1.2.1/kotlinx-serialization-kotlinx-serialization-json-js-legacy.js"></script>
  <script src="../packages_imported/ktor-ktor-utils-js-legacy/1.6.0/ktor-ktor-utils-js-legacy.js"></script>
  <script src="../packages_imported/ktor-ktor-http-js-legacy/1.6.0/ktor-ktor-http-js-legacy.js"></script>
  <script src="../packages_imported/ktor-ktor-http-cio-js-legacy/1.6.0/ktor-ktor-http-cio-js-legacy.js"></script>
  <script src="../packages_imported/ktor-ktor-client-core-js-legacy/1.6.0/ktor-ktor-client-core-js-legacy.js"></script>
  <script src="./parippu-vada/kotlin/parippu-vada.js"></script>
  <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

This throws the following error:

```
_Collections.kt:1618 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'iterator')
    at _Collections.kt:1618
    at parippu-vada.js:23
    at parippu-vada.js:25
```

Its shows error in collections.kt @:

```
/**
 * Applies the given [transform] function to each element of the original collection
 * and appends the results to the given [destination].
 */
public inline fun <T, R, C : MutableCollection<in R>> Iterable<T>.mapTo(destination: C, transform: (T) -> R): C {
    for (item in this) <- this throw error
        destination.add(transform(item))
    return destination
}
```

Its probably related to kotlin version because the error is in auto-generated file. Is there anything I can do about this.

Am almost giving up on kmm, some inspiration would be nice !

Comment: It's likely that you pass something to `mapTo` that is not a kotlin `Iterable` instance. Could you show what code is in lines 23-25 in parippu-vada.js?

Comment: Those lines are where the file is getting loaded:


    `}root['parippu-vada'] = factory(typeof this['parippu-vada'] === 'undefined' ? {} : this['parippu-vada'], this['kotlin'], this['KotlinBigInteger-bignum-js-legacy'], this['ktor-ktor-io-js-legacy'], this['kotlinx-serialization-kotlinx-serialization-json-js-legacy'], this['kotlinx-serialization-kotlinx-serialization-core-js-legacy'], this['ktor-ktor-client-core-js-legacy'], this['ktor-ktor-http-js-legacy'], this['kotlinx-coroutines-core']);
  }
}'

Comment: @llya I havent started running any code, as the loading of the file parippu-vada.js itself is failing. For some reason it throws error here and loading of file fails.